# NetBeans Gradle build results in InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle, build, classnotfoundexception

Dears,

I am completely new to Grandle, so bear with me.

I have an application that works fine in the IDE. It is based on the tutorial of the Google Sheet API, extended with some other functionality.

After the first build running the .jar file told me it did not have a Main function defined, but adding

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'WordCards'
    }
}
```

solved this problem. Now when I try to run the .jar outside of the IDE, I get numerous exceptions, including `InvocationTargetException` that is resulted by a `ClassNotFoundException`

I guess something is not right with the packaging, but I have no idea what to look for.

this is the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'WordCards'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'WordCards'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev10-1.22.0'


}
```

and this is how one of the classes looks like (this is not the main class, I'm copying this one in, because I suspect this class has the dependencies that result in the error):

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class SheetsQuickstart {

    List<List<Object>> values;
    private HashMap<Integer, List> validWords;
    private ArrayList<Integer> validKeys;
    ValueRange response;
    String spreadsheetId;

    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
        "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart.json");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart.json
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
            SheetsQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Sheets API client service.
     * @return an authorized Sheets API client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public SheetsQuickstart() throws IOException {
        this.spreadsheetId = "12TpmJ5ULEbwfFUd3ZgNnHDMEQdIiJWZGOlgXwdTcPAc";
        // Build a new authorized API client service.

        //WordCards wordcards = new WordCards();

        Sheets service = getSheetsService();

        // Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
        // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
        String spreadsheetId = "12TpmJ5ULEbwfFUd3ZgNnHDMEQdIiJWZGOlgXwdTcPAc";
        String range = "Sheet1!A2:D";
        response = service.spreadsheets().values()
            .get(spreadsheetId, range)
            .execute();
        values = response.getValues();
        if (values == null || values.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No data found.");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Actual, Target");
         /* for (List row : values) {
            // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            try {
            System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", row.get(0), row.get(1));
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("Itt most valami üres");
            }
          }*/

         System.out.println("A 202.sor: ");
                 List row202 = values.get(200);
                 System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", row202.get(0), row202.get(1));
        }
    }
    List printRow (int n) {
        List row = values.get(n-2);
        return row;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param k
     * @return number of rows of the get(k) column
     * 
     * this method will go through the k column, and check how many values are not null
     * it will return the number of valid values it finds
     */
    int countTheRows (int k) {
        validWords = new HashMap<>();
        validKeys = new ArrayList<>();
        int e=0;
        for (List row : values) {
            if (row.get(k) != "") {
                storeValidWords(e,row);
                e++;
            }
        }
        return e;
    }
    private void storeValidWords(int e, List row) {
        validWords.put(e, row);
        validKeys.add(e);
    }
    List getRandomWord() {
        if (validWords.isEmpty() || validKeys.isEmpty())
        {
            throw new AssertionError("The valid words and valid keys must not be empty when calling a random word!");
        }
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(validKeys.size());
        Integer key = validKeys.get(index);
            if (!(key instanceof Integer))
            {
                throw new AssertionError ("The retrieved key must be of Integer type!");
            }
            return validWords.get(key);
   }

    /**
     * This is for writing only
     */
    void WriteExample2() throws IOException {
        Sheets service = getSheetsService();
        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

               List<CellData> values = new ArrayList<>();
               values.add(new CellData()
                    .setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue()
                            .setStringValue("Hello World!")));
            requests.add(new Request()
                    .setUpdateCells(new UpdateCellsRequest()
                            .setStart(new GridCoordinate()
                                    .setSheetId(895100899)
                                    .setRowIndex(0)
                                    .setColumnIndex(0))
                            .setRows(Arrays.asList(
                                    new RowData().setValues(values)))
                            .setFields("userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor")));

         BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
                    .setRequests(requests);
            service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, batchUpdateRequest)
                    .execute();
    }
      void WriteToCell(int row, int column, String value) throws IOException {
        Sheets service = getSheetsService();
        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

               List<CellData> values = new ArrayList<>();
               values.add(new CellData()
                    .setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue()
                            .setStringValue(value)));
            requests.add(new Request()
                    .setUpdateCells(new UpdateCellsRequest()
                            .setStart(new GridCoordinate()
                                    .setSheetId(895100899)
                                    .setRowIndex(row)
                                    .setColumnIndex(column))
                            .setRows(Arrays.asList(
                                    new RowData().setValues(values)))
                            .setFields("userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor")));

         BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
                    .setRequests(requests);
            service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, batchUpdateRequest)
                    .execute();
    }
    void WriteToCell(int row, int column, int value) throws IOException {
        Sheets service = getSheetsService();
        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

               List<CellData> values = new ArrayList<>();
               values.add(new CellData()
                    .setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue()
                            .setNumberValue((double)value)));
            requests.add(new Request()
                    .setUpdateCells(new UpdateCellsRequest()
                            .setStart(new GridCoordinate()
                                    .setSheetId(895100899)
                                    .setRowIndex(row)
                                    .setColumnIndex(column))
                            .setRows(Arrays.asList(
                                    new RowData().setValues(values)))
                            .setFields("userEnteredValue,userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor")));

         BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest()
                    .setRequests(requests);
            service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, batchUpdateRequest)
                    .execute();
    }

    String getCellValue(String range) throws IOException {
        Sheets service = getSheetsService();
        response = service.spreadsheets().values()
            .get(spreadsheetId, range)
            .execute();
        values = response.getValues();
        List valuesList = values.get(0);
        return valuesList.get(0).toString();
    }

}
```

Once again, the code is working fine within the IDE

Any help would be much appreciated
Zsolt

Comment: Is your main class inside a package?

Comment: No, it's in default package